# insert into select mysql two database

Tags: mysql, t-sql

is there any similar syntax to this in mysql:

insert into database2.table1 (column1, column2) select column4, column5 from database2.table1;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Database Link - MySQL Equivalent ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent)

Comment: there's only one database in your example.. did you mean insert into database2.table1 (column1, column2) select column4, column5 from database1.table1

Comment: @duffymo, that question inspired me for a solution using views, thanks for that

Comment: @ben: my mistake , they are two

Comment: that might be what he meant, but it works either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks good.  are you getting an error?

Comment: yep.  glad i could help i guess?

Answer (score 0):

I create a view for the columns I wanted to copy

than i run this query:

insert into database2.table1 (column1, column2) select * from database1.view;