# database link between two mysql servers running in two different locations

Tags: mysql

Please tell me how to connect to mysql database server from another mysql database server running in two different locations and access all the tables and update them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik there is no direct "database link" in mysql like there is in oracle. what you can do is master-master [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) of two databases and then update locally. similar question with more info:

[Oracle Database Link - MySQL Equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

You could pop a [MySQL Proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) client between the two servers and send your queries to it and let it do all the talking backwards and forwards between the other boxes.