# how to select from one database and insert into another Database in a Single query with different Database connections in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database1");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO database2.categories (category_name,description,group_id,created)
  SELECT table1.name, table1.description, 12, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  FROM GiveArang_categories Where `p_id`= '225' ");
```

I need to insert data into the second database which is selected from the first database.
Both databases have different connections. It needs to done in php in a single query .

Comment: You can't pass two link_identifiers at the same time. So I think it's pretty impossible. Well, it's just me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this (that I know of) is by two separate connections.

Something like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database2");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO database2.categories (category_name,description,group_id,created)");
mysql_close();

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database1");
mysql_query("SELECT table1.name, table1.description, 12, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM GiveArang_categories Where `p_id`= '225' ");
mysql_close();
```

Comment: This is Working 
mysql_connect($host1,$username1,$password1);
mysql_select_db($db_name1);
$cat_name=mysql_query("SELECT table1.name FROM table1 Where `p_id`= '1234' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($cat_name))
{
    while($var = mysql_fetch_array($cat_name)){
mysql_connect($host2,$username2,$password2);
mysql_select_db($db_name1);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table2.name2 (description,gid,created) values ('". $var['name']."','". $var['name']."','15',UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");


    }
}
mysql_close();

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no Oracle dblink (which is what you need to connect to another database in a single query in Oracle Database) equivalent in MySql.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530252/database-link-between-two-mysql-servers-running-in-two-different-locations) for further information.

Comment: Oracle has a functionality called dblink which let a single query to connect to different databases with different connections, which is the exact feature he would need in MySql

Answer (score 0):

You can pop a [MySQL Proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) to sit between your server and database boxes which will allow you to treat them as if they are on the same server. You can then use `databasename.tablename` within your query to identify your different databases via the same connection.

Comment: Interesting, but physically there are nevertheless executed several queries.

Answer (score 0):

If both databases are on the same mysql-server you can note it like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO database2.categories (category_name,description,group_id,created)
  SELECT database1.table1.name, database1.table1.description, 12, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  FROM database1.GiveArang_categories Where database1.GiveArang_categories.p_id= '225' ");
```