# Two MySQL Database on Jhipster

Tags: java, mysql, spring, liquibase, jhipster

I am using jHipster and it is great as most of the boiler-plate Java code is automatically generated.

In my application, I need two MySQL databases. How do I configure them? Should I have two different database config files for the two different schemas?

Also, jHipster uses Liquibase, so how do I change my DatabaseConfiguration class?

Comment: Are you sure you need two schemas?  That is, you can't create tables with foreign keys?

Comment: Not only two schemas they are in two different DBs one MSSQL and other MySQL

Comment: Ok, you may want to update the question to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

- You will need to configure 2 datasources, 2 Hibernate sessions, 2 cache instances... This is going to be quite complex: first start with the datasources (obviously!).
- Please note that transactions won't work between your two databases, so this can lead to some interesting bugs :-)

Another solution, which I would prefer, is to use [something similar to Oracle DB Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent). That would solve all those problems and be much easier to work on.

Comment: Your Point No 1 is something which I can look at. But how do we configure it with liquibase. Any sample application would help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if you talk about spring, but since you added the spring tag, I assume you do.

As far as I see, the basic question is, wether you need an XA-transaction or not (update both databases within the same transaction). If you do, then you simply define your datasources with an appropriate MySql XA-Datasource and bind them to the same transactionmanger (which of course has to support XA-transactions).

If you do this configuration in one or more spring-config-xml files (or java classes, if you prefer annotation based spring configuration) is up to you.