# Attempt for Two DataSources in JHipster

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, datasource, jhipster

I am attempting to establish two DataSources for a JHipster project, one for the application credentials (utilizing OAuth2 Authentication) and one for the actual data portion (entities). Below are my configuration files. I tried to mimic the original HikariDataSource connection JHipster comes with inheritly and I think my connection works.

My problem arises from the creation of a new Hibernate Session and Jpa linking through the @Transactional annotation. It seems that the @Autowired variables that worked with normal JHipster do not work anymore due to something I wrote.

I've been stuck figuring this problem out and I have come to a stand still. The error in the log states invalid column type but when I checked the schema.xml the timestamp type is correct. I'm unsure where the tinyblob check is coming from.

Looking above I see that the beans aren't being created correctly. The entityManager I created doesn't seem to be configuring correctly. Any help will be appreciated!

I also didn't know which files to include so I included the few below for reference. If others are needed, I will include them.

I have also included some references I have used along my way to help aid my progress.

UserDetailsService.java

```
package com.mycompany.testoauth2.security;

import com.mycompany.testoauth2.domain.creds.User;
import com.mycompany.testoauth2.repository.creds.UserRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Authenticate a user from the database.
 */
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional("customEntityTransactionManager")
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
        return userFromDatabase.map(user -> {
            if (!user.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin,
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the " +
        "database"));
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.mycompany.testoauth2.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension;


import javax.inject.Inject;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/api/register")
            .antMatchers("/api/activate")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().realmName("TestOAuth2")
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.mycompany.testoauth2.repository.creds;

import com.mycompany.testoauth2.domain.creds.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the User entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findOneByActivationKey(String activationKey);

    List<User> findAllByActivatedIsFalseAndCreatedDateBefore(ZonedDateTime dateTime);

    Optional<User> findOneByResetKey(String resetKey);

    Optional<User> findOneByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findOneByLogin(String login);

    Optional<User> findOneById(Long userId);

    @Override
    void delete(User t);

}
```

DatabaseConfiguration.java

```
package com.mycompany.testoauth2.config;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import com.mycompany.testoauth2.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-multiple-db.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.mycompany.testoauth2.repository",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "customEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "customEntityTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);
    private HikariDataSource credsDb;
    private HikariDataSource dataDb;

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Primary
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{!environment.acceptsProfiles('" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD + "') && !environment.acceptsProfiles('" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_HEROKU + "')}")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }

        credsDb =  (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
            .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
            .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
            .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .build();

        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            credsDb.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return credsDb;
    }

    @Bean(name = "customEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customEntityManager() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource(new DataSourceProperties()));
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.testoauth2.domain.creds");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;

    }

    @Bean(name = "customEntityTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager customEntityTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(customEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties,
                                     LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

        // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
        } else {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }

        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module();
    }

    public HikariDataSource getCredsDb() { return credsDb; }
    public HikariDataSource getDataDb() { return dataDb; }

}
```

Error Log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.testoauth2.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.testoauth2.repository.creds.UserRepository com.mycompany.testoauth2.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#8ef2c72' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8ef2c72': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customEntityManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/testoauth2/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in app_cred.jhi_persistent_audit_event for column event_date. Found: timestamp, expected: tinyblob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at...
```

Multiple DataSources JHipster (Unanswered): [@36808461](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808461/jhipster-multiple-databases)
Two DataSource JHipster Reference: [@31240475](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240475/two-mysql-database-on-jhipster)

Jpa Two Datasources Link: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases