# MySQL view with data from PostgreSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is it possible to create in MySQL a view connected to a PostgreSQL table so an application using the MySQL connection can read the information of the table in PostgreSQL?

```
MySQL           PostgreSQL
-----           ----------
view_01   <-    table_01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it isn't. if you look at Oracle databases, they have something called [database links](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm), which doesn't seem to be the same case for [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent).