# mysql equivalent to oracle's dblink

Tags: mysql, oracle, dblink

I already have oracle 12c and this DB has dblinks to others oracle databases. Now I want to migrate this oracle 12c but I will lose the dblinks, is there any equivalent functionality from mysql or mariadb? All the answers i found in stack are outdated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent is one answer but it is from 2009

Comment: The accepted answer for the duplicate question is still valid.