# Getting error while implementing joins on multiple DSL contexts from different databases in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I want to execute one query having joins with the tables related to different DSLCONTEXT which are related to different databases.Below is the example of what I am trying to do :

```
DSLContext ctx1;
DSLContext ctx2;
Val findDetails= ctx1.select(table1(**from ctx1**). innerjoin(table2)(**from ctx2**).on(table2.column.eq(table1.column)).asTable();
```

While executing the above query getting table2 doesn't exist.

I am expecting to use something like ctx2. Table2 inside the query.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL for both the databases

Comment: Hi, Lukas, thanks for responding on my query. Please let me know if there are some more details needed from my end. I am kind of stuck in this issue and wanted to know whether it's possible to use join with multiple contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the reason for you to have two distinct `DSLContext` instances is because you have separate JDBC `Connection` instances, and you're connecting to separate database instances. To my knowledge, it isn't possible to use [Oracle style database links or PostgreSQL style foreign data wrappers in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565993/521799), so you cannot join between the two tables in a single query. You'll have to run both queries separately, and join the data in the client, e.g.:

```java
Result<?> r1 = ctx1.select(..).from(..).where(..).fetch();
Result<?> r2 = ctx2.select(..).from(..).where(
    CORRELATION.ID.in(r1.getValues(...))).fetch();
```

Of course, it may well be that there isn't really a need for two separate `DSLContext` instances, if the two databases are on the same server, but you didn't specify those details. In any case, jOOQ can't do that for you.

Comment: Hi Lukas, yes I have created two DSL contexts because both the databases are on different servers. I am able to fetch the data from both the databases in separate queries using the two DSL contexts. I will try implementing joins as you suggested . Thanks for your inputs @Lukas.